# Blazor CRUD Template not working in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: blazor-server-side

I have downloaded Blazor CRUD Template. When I run this in Visual Studio 2019 it shows an error message:

> Error: There was an unhandled exception on the current circuit, so this circuit will be terminated. For more details turn on detailed exceptions by setting 'DetailedErrors: true' in 'appSettings.Development.json' or set 'CircuitOptions.DetailedError".

Please advise how I might fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exactly without knowing where you got the template from, but the exception message is self-explanatory about how to get more information about the error. ASP.NET Core is restricting the amount of detail it is showing in case you're using this in a public context.

If you don't have one, create a file in the root of your project called `appSettings.Development.json` and paste the following into it:

```json
{
  "DetailedErrors": true
}
```

If you do already have this file, simply add a comma after the last element in the root of the JSON object (e.g., before the closing '}') and add this on the next line following your comma (this should look similar to the syntax described above):

```json
"DetailedErrors: true
```

Re-run the application and it should provide more information about why it's not working.